# PHP: ZipArchive::extractTo() doesn't complete unzipping

Tags: php, zip, ipa, php-ziparchive

I'm using `ZipArchive` to unzip files. It's working great, except for ONE file so far (it's 10.6MB, if that matters).

The problem is, `ZipArchive::extractTo()` returns `FALSE`, and that's correct since if fails.

BUT it doesn't completely fails: half of the file is being unzipped, and then it returns `FALSE`.

As this method doesn't throw any `Exception`, `FALSE` is not really great to understand what happened in the middle of that unzipping journey. If anyone already ran into that problem, i'd love some help :) Thanks!

Comment: check if this file has some special character in name, or if the destination folder already exists with a non write permission.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but everything is alright on that side. I believe it wouldn't even extract almost half the archive if that was not the case.

Comment: Hi!

I'm running a similar issue with a 100 folders ZIP, with around 3k XML files per folder.

I can only extractTo 20 folders (and the containing files). No Exception or Return check.

JFYI.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is different, but I think you're running into a memory issue.

Try to force this:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

set_time_limit(0);`

Also, try to get memory usage before and after script, and deal with the total:

`$mem_before = memory_get_usage();

/* your script code here */

$mem_after = memory_get_usage();

printf('Memory used: %1$s bytes', ($mem_after - $mem_before));`

Maybe this points you in the right direction. ;)

Best!
**R**